# Backbone on route not giving me the route in the callback

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to call the `router.on('route', callback)` function, but the callback is not provided with the route ...

My router/app:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone')
Backbone.$ = $
var _ = require('underscore')
var App = Backbone.Router.extend({
    // nothing here yet
}, {
    instance: null,
    getInstance: function () {
        App.instance = App.instance || new App
        return App.instance
    }
})
module.exports = App
```

Some module using the router:

```
var IndexView = require('./views/IndexView')
var App = require('../../AppModule/js/main')

var _ = require('underscore')
var Backbone = require('backbone')
Backbone.$ = $

function IndexModule(opts) {

    this.app = App.getInstance()

    this.indexView = new IndexView({
        view: opts.view
    })

    this.init = function() {
        this.app.route('', _.bind(this.indexRoute, this))
        this.app.route('testroute#:id', function(id) {
            console.log(id)
        })
        this.app.on('route', _.bind(this.routeChanged, this))
    }

    this.indexRoute = function() {
        this.indexView.render()
    }

    this.routeChanged = function() {
        console.log(arguments)
    }

}

module.exports = IndexModule
```

Somewhere form `$(document).ready()`:

```
var indexModule = new IndexModule({
    view: "someview.html"
})
indexModule.init()
Backbone.history.start({root: '/'});
```

If I go to `testroute/2` I get this result:

```
["", ["2"]]
```

Shouldn't the route (testroute) come up in an argument as a string??

Thanks..

Comment: The route that you have bound to is testroute#:id. It should be testroute/:id

Comment: I tried both, neither works

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that you have setup the route as  testroute/:id. Since id is the only variable here, only that is passed as an argument to the handler. You should try something like `:routeName/:id` This way, both the route name and id will be passed as arguments.